# ADB server not running

Tags: android, adb, daemon

When I run ADB and type in "adb start-server" it says

```
*daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
could not read ok from ADB Server, error = 109
*failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

what should I do? I've tried killing the server and restarting the pc but nothing seems to work. my pc recognizes the phone and the adb process only appears briefly when i try to start the server. also, it gets stuck on wating for device when i type "fastboot oem unlock"

Comment: Sounds like a system configuration issue - firewall, something else already on that port, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i've tried it with the usb in every port and gave adb.exe permission through firewall and antivirus. still nothing...

Comment: TCP port, (the 5037) not USB port. Windows is by far the least suitable OS choice for Android work anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know, but I don't have any other OS available here... Well, I suppose port 5037 is free, given Resource Monitor doesn't list it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like windows is messing up the ports (reserving them). I have the same issue with docker containers and this worked for me:

Run this in the command line (as administrator)

```
net stop winnat
adb.exe start-server
net start winnat
```

Comment: `netstat -aon|findstr "5037" ` returns empty list, and your way works for me!

Comment: this is the only solution from ~5 issues about this on SO that actually works when there is no other process running from ADB, and I had too look up my votes to even find this one again - note you have to run `net stop/start` as admin

Comment: Thank you @proc, I've added the admin part.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to save time.

Answer (score 13):

Happened with me as well. Just check there might be an existing adb process running in your task manager. Just kill the process and run the 'adb start-server' command.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me today.

I realized it happened when I started Android Studio after having my Genymotion emulator running, so I fixed it by closing everything (even check task manager for a running instance of adb).
After closing everything, I opened Android Studio first and then the emulator and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in IntelliJ IDEA plugin - Aladdin Logcat. Turned it off and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had Oculus Developer Hub open.

Even if you're not using its adb features, it will constantly try to start its own version of adb and kill the one you're trying to launch.